# MariaDB: Multiple joins and where clause searching for 1 in TINYINT Column not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tinyint

I have tables called `person` and `book` and `image` and `bookhit`.

Person has `id`, `name` and Book has `id`, `owner_id`, `info` and Image has a column for `id`, `owner_id`, `url` and `thumbnail` which is a TINYINT (In the database half the rows are `0`s and `1`s.) By the way, the image column stores images of the cover of the book in two version: big-one and thumbnail. The table `bookhit` stores the times the book has been retrieved from the database and has a column `hits`.

So I tried multiple INNER JOIN to retrieve all the thumbnails for the most popular books. The SQL Query is the following:

```
SELECT `imagehit`.`hits`, `person`.`name`, `book`.`info`, `image`.`url`, `image`.`thumbnail` FROM `imagehit`
INNER JOIN `person` ON `person`.`id`=`book`.`owner_id`
INNER JOIN `image` ON `image`.`owner_id`=`book`.`id`
ORDER BY `imagehit`.`hits` DESC
WHERE `image`.`thumbnail`=1
LIMIT 10;
```

And that doesn't work, even though half rows has `1`s  in `image`.`thumbnail`  . If I change the following line:

```
WHERE `image`.`thumbnail`=1
```

To

```
WHERE `image`.`thumbnail`=0
```

It does work. Well, I went to the `image` table and did a simple query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `image` WHERE `image`.`thumbnail`=0;
```

And gave me **total** rows stored in the table. But when I browse `image` table in `phpMyAdmin` I see there are `1`s stored in the table. :(

Any ideas why this happens? thank you in advance.

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `thumbnail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `image_url` (`url`),
 KEY `image_owner_id` (`owner_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `image_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1450 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `person` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `person_url` (`url`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6287 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `book` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `book` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
 `info` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `book_url` (`url`),
 KEY `book_owner_id` (`owner_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=725 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `imagehit` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `imagehit_person_id` (`person_id`),
 KEY `imagehit_owner_id` (`owner_id`),
 KEY `hits` (`hits`),
 CONSTRAINT `imagehit_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `image` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `imagehit_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=725 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Proof I'm not crazy: 
[image]

I inserted the data using Peewee, when I created the row I set `thumbnail=True` if the image was a **thumbnail** and as `thumbnail=False` if it wasn't. The column `thumbnail` is the field `BooleanField` in Peewee.

Comment: Show us your table definition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your interest. I edited my question and the definitions are there. :-)

Comment: Are you _certain_ that you ever had `1`s in the table?  How did you insert the data in the first place?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the question. I'm positive there are `1`s in the table. I added a picture of it and I added the rows using peewee. `thumbnail=True` or `thumbnail=False`.

Comment: Your query is inconsistent with the screen capture, and I would be inclined to believe the query.

Comment: What does `SELECT \`image\`.\`thumbnail\` FROM \`image\`;` show you?

Comment: It shows all the records with the proper values. I first add the normal image so the first row shows `0` and the second row (the thumbnail for the first image show `1` and so on...

Comment: OK my last attempt: Try using `WHERE \`image\`.\`thumbnail\`= TRUE` ... what do you get now?

Comment: I'll check my Python code because when I do `WHERE image.thumbnail=TRUE` returns all the rows (the total in the table as 1. Then I do `WHERE image.thumbnail=FALSE` returns all the rows as 0. Sigh, something went very wrong.

Comment: Your observations are not consistent with what you think the state of your data is.  Yes, please check the Python code, and you might want to open a new question with this information.

Comment: There are typos in the `SELECT` -- you don't have an `ON` for `imagehit`, nor a `JOIN book`.  Please fix.